# Splitting text to multiple columns based on delimiter in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to load data from a stage table to final table in SQL server. My column delimiter is a pipe character "|". But I'm getting pipe characters in the text column as shown below.

My data in the stage table is as shown below:

1233|"abcd,edfg"|asdf|3456

1234|xyz|"abnd|tfgt"|8765

I'm trying to write a scalar function which take split the contents of the stage table into multiple columns based on pipe as delimiter.

Desired Output should be:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | `"abcd|edfg"` | asdf | 3456 |
| 1234 | xyz | `"abnd|tfgt"` | 8765 |

If I'm trying to split this using substring and charindex functions in SQL server, I end up splitting "abcd" and edfg into 2 separate columns there by causing column shifting issue.

What would be the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't store such values to begin with. This is an extremely serious design bug, it breaks even the most basic design rule. One cell should contain a single atomic value

Comment: It's far easier to split and clean data *before* storing it in the database. It's easier eg to write a Python or C# script that splits multi-value input and stores each value in separate rows in another table. If the data is already stored in production, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and store the extra values in a different table

Comment: This the design for my staging table. Its just to load the data temporarily, post that we do column  splitting and load into final tables. Final tables are designed in proper columnar format.

Comment: Split the data *before* loading it into the staging table. Where did this come from? Are the double quotes really there? There may be ways to avoid this altogether. Eg if you load the data from a text file, you can specify `|` as the field delimiter. `"abnd|tfgt"` is trickier, as this says that the CSV contains a *single* string containing `abnd|tfgt`. SQL and specifically T-SQL are terrible at string manipulation. If you have to parse a custom format, it's a LOT easier to do it in another language

Comment: Let's say someone had the bright idea of createing a multi-value "CSV'" format. It's far easier to write a simple parser in C# than try to handle this in SQL. In C# you could use `ReadLine` to load one line at a time, `String.Split` to split cells and then another `String.Split` to split the "multi-value" fields.

Comment: The staging table is used to load data into multiple tables, each target table has a different schema. So initially we load data into the stage table, load it into the specific target table. Then truncate the stage table and reload it with data from a different file and load it into another final table. This is an iterative process.

Comment: Even if you need to load the rows from the staging table, it's a *lot* easier to use C# or a Python script to parse the data.

Comment: Also, there is a type in my above question, the 1st line in my input should be  as shown below 
1233|"abcd|edfg"|asdf|3456

Comment: Staging tables aren't multi-purpose. They're meant to make parsing specific input easier, not become the parsing problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are always two values, just use string functions:

```
select s.*,
       left(col_2, charindex('|', col_2 + '|') - 1) as col_2_left,
       stuff(col_2, 1, charindex('|', col_2 + '|'), '') as col_2_right
from staging s;
```

You would need to repeat this for each column that could have duplicates.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a27556971024fc573fcc613e796328b3) is a db<>fiddle.